# Box, linear gradient, css and javascript

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, box

I'm working with react JS and i look for a solution for linear gradient in different Box. When i have three same box in a row.
I'have an example :
When I've three same box like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWz6E.png)

It Should be like that :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81A5M.png)

Do you have anea idea about this ?

Thanks;

Comment: Do you have exactly 3 boxes ?

Comment: I have  totaly 13 boxes, and if in these boxes I have a set of three boxes with the same radient I need to propage the radient only through these three box.

Comment: So you have a grid of 3 by 5 and each row should have is gradient ?

Comment: I have only one row and it possible to have from 0 to 13 box with consecutive gradient

Comment: I edited my answer have a look and tel me if it helped you

Answer (score 1):

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box--gradient {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#2a6496, #fff 70%, #011852);
}
```

```html
<div class="box box--gradient"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the background to the container, and have another element who will cover all unused space from the child elements (and hide the background in that area)

```css
html, body {
  background-color: white;
}
.cont {
  display:flex;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow, green, blue) no-repeat;
}
.spacer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  flex-shrink:0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<h1>One box</h1>
<div class="cont">
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
<h1>Three boxes</h1>
<div class="cont">
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
```

#### Update

According to last comment I understand there gonna be few different gradients boxes in a row, while up to 3 can come in a row, and in this case they should collapce. in that case I offer this:

```css
.cont {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}
.grad-1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow, green);
}
.grad-2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, blue, purple, pink);
}
.grad-3 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white,silver, black);
}
[class^=grad]{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  flex-shrink:0;
  background-size: 300% 100%;
  background-position: top left;
}
.grad-1+.grad-1,.grad-2+.grad-2,.grad-3+.grad-3 {
    background-position: top center;
}
.grad-1+.grad-1+.grad-1,.grad-2+.grad-2+.grad-2,.grad-3+.grad-3+.grad-3 {
    background-position: top right;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
<div class="grad-1"></div>
<div class="grad-1"></div>
<div class="grad-3"></div>
<div class="grad-2"></div>
<div class="grad-2"></div>
<div class="grad-2"></div>
<div class="grad-3"></div>
<div class="grad-1"></div>
<div class="grad-1"></div>
<div class="grad-3"></div>
<div class="grad-3"></div>
<div class="grad-3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah that's right but there can be 0 or n successive gradient in the 13 box row

Answer (score 0):

You can either add a big background and change its position

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, blue, red);
  background-size: 1300%;
}

.box:nth-child(1) {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  background-position: 8.33% 0;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  background-position: 16.66% 0;
}

.box:nth-child(4) {
  background-position: 25% 0;
}

.box:nth-child(5) {
  background-position: 33.33% 0;
}

.box:nth-child(6) {
  background-position: 41.66% 0;
}

.box:nth-child(7) {
  background-position: 50% 0;
}

.box:nth-child(8) {
  background-position: 58.33% 0;
}

.box:nth-child(9) {
  background-position: 66.66% 0;
}

.box:nth-child(10) {
  background-position: 75% 0;
}

.box:nth-child(11) {
  background-position: 83.33% 0;
}

.box:nth-child(12) {
  background-position: 91.66% 0;
}

.box:nth-child(13) {
  background-position: 100% 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>
<div class="box">5</div>
<div class="box">6</div>
<div class="box">7</div>
<div class="box">8</div>
<div class="box">9</div>
<div class="box">10</div>
<div class="box">11</div>
<div class="box">12</div>
<div class="box">13</div>
```

Or Add your boxes to a container that have this background

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, blue, red);
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @tantraki I edited the first snippet, tell me if it fits your needs

Comment: I think I don't explain myself well : for exemple one case can be : [red-box] [gradient-box] [green-box] [gradient-box] [gradient-box] [gradient-box] [blue-box]

Comment: Do you know the exact patern you will get ?

Comment: Yes,  always 13 boxes, but the color is chosen by the user (by button) : ( red, blue, green,yellow, grey, black or gradient. If the user choose to have two gradient consecutive; the system need to collapse the gradient

Comment: Two or more consecutive gradient

Comment: Did you have an idea ?

Comment: is it always the gradient ?

Comment: No a box can be a simple color or a gradient

Comment: Yeah but the gradient will always be red to blue (for exemple)

Comment: No it depends on the color before and after the box (or the boxes)  who contains the gradient

Comment: You will have to generate classes with javascript but it's definitely possible :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution :

You have 3 boxes so, add a color for the first one, a gradient for the second and a color for the last one... (check my demo)

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="box"> </div>
          <div className="box"> </div>
          <div className="box"> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
}
```

**Styles.css**

```
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.row .box:first-of-type {
  height: 150px;
  width: 33%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #44107a;
}
.row .box {
  height: 150px;
  width: 33%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #44107a 0%, #ff0032 100%);
}
.row .box:last-of-type {
  height: 150px;
  width: 33%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #ff0032;
}
```

Demo : [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/box-linear-gradient-css-and-javascript?file=src/App.js)